# Is it possible to install puppet-sync post receive hook on Bitbucket site to sync my Puppet master automatically after each push?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I recently started using Puppet directory environments. I really like the idea of Dynamic Puppet environments with Git branches and Git hooks to sync Puppet master after any changes were pushed to the Git server.

My question is:
Can I use external service like Bitbucket as a Git master or do I need to have my own Git server? If I can use Bitbucket how I can add my puppet-sync post receive hook there? Can anybody point me to an article on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the idea of repository hosting services (like GitHub or BitBucket) is to:

- *not* execute directly any program (for security reason)
- provide [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) or [bitbucket Post hook management](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management) in order to notify a *listener* which has to act on a JSON payload message.

If you use an external hosting service, you would need to setup such a webhook *and* a listener in order to sync your service (here a Puppet master) after each push to your Git repo.
A bit like [that webhook](https://gist.github.com/ddonovan/3e81e686885317955e78) (to listen to push events) but [calling `puppet-sync` instead](https://gist.github.com/zipkid/5772556).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

As far as I understand it's possible but not a piece of cake :)
So now I need to decide for myself if it worth it or easy just use the internal Git server :)

Thanks again!